# Multiple Linear Regression-Interactions Between Transformed Quadratic Variable and Factor Variable

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I have a multiple linear regression as seen below that contains interaction terms, where some of my terms are factor variables (season, month, holiday, weekday, weathersit)

```
regwithint=lm(casual~season:temp+season:month+year:temp+
            month:temp+holiday:temp+weekday:hum+season+
            month+holiday+weekday+weathersit+temp+windspeed
          ,data=training)
```

However, the variables temp and windspeed were transformed to (temp^3) and (windspeed^2).

Looking at the interaction terms, I have an interaction between **temp:weekday**
where temp is **temp^3** and weekday is a **factor** variable.

I know for most cases I should use ***I(temp^3)*** but does the fact that it is paired with a factor variable mean I should use **poly(temp,3,raw=T)** instead?

Thank You.

Comment: This question seems strangely familiar.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's establish that `I()` works fine with factor variable interactions:

```
data(iris)
reg <- lm(Sepal.Length~Species:I(Petal.Length^2), data=iris)
summary(reg)
```

> ```
> Call:
> lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Species:I(Petal.Length^2), data = iris)
>
> Residuals:
>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
> -0.87875 -0.22363 -0.00197  0.21664  1.06243 
>
> Coefficients:
>                                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> (Intercept)                         4.245539   0.133172  31.880  < 2e-16 ***
> Speciessetosa:I(Petal.Length^2)     0.341688   0.062196   5.494  1.7e-07 ***
> Speciesversicolor:I(Petal.Length^2) 0.092381   0.007413  12.462  < 2e-16 ***
> Speciesvirginica:I(Petal.Length^2)  0.075714   0.004388  17.253  < 2e-16 ***
> ---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Residual standard error: 0.3431 on 146 degrees of freedom
> Multiple R-squared:  0.8318,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.8284 
> F-statistic: 240.7 on 3 and 146 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
> ```

Now let's see if your function works too:

```
data(iris)
reg <- lm(Sepal.Length~Species: poly(Petal.Length,2,raw=T), data=iris)
summary(reg)
```

It does (note it's different in that it necessary has the lower order term too):

> ```
> Call:
> lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Species:poly(Petal.Length, 2, raw = T), 
>     data = iris)
>
> Residuals:
>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
> -0.73849 -0.22814 -0.01978  0.24177  0.98833 
>
> Coefficients:
>                                                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
> (Intercept)                                        1.79002    1.58957   1.126   0.2620  
> Speciessetosa:poly(Petal.Length, 2, raw = T)1      3.87221    2.16771   1.786   0.0762 .
> Speciesversicolor:poly(Petal.Length, 2, raw = T)1  1.13016    0.78109   1.447   0.1501  
> Speciesvirginica:poly(Petal.Length, 2, raw = T)1   0.74216    0.56640   1.310   0.1922  
> Speciessetosa:poly(Petal.Length, 2, raw = T)2     -1.12847    0.74087  -1.523   0.1299  
> Speciesversicolor:poly(Petal.Length, 2, raw = T)2 -0.03641    0.09628  -0.378   0.7059  
> Speciesvirginica:poly(Petal.Length, 2, raw = T)2   0.02178    0.05107   0.426   0.6705  
> ---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Residual standard error: 0.3367 on 143 degrees of freedom
> Multiple R-squared:  0.8413,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.8346 
> F-statistic: 126.4 on 6 and 143 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
> ```

So what's the difference?

Well, like I was saying in your other question basically just that `I()` is what the vast majority of R programmers use in `lm` and `glm` equations because it's far more flexible -- can be used for any transformation within the equation.

But to each his own. SO disallows opinion-based questions, so I'm going to interpret the question as "do both work?" to which the answer is "yes" and "why is I() used ubiquitously?" to which the answer is "it's flexible to any transformation". As for whether you ***should*** use it, that's not a question we can legitimately ask or answer on SO, but you could probably ask it on the Programmers Stack Exchange (or whatever they're calling it these days) or the Code Review Stack Exchange.